# Exclusive query using SQL IN()

Tags: mysql, select

This query is pretty self explanatory:

```
$networks = '6,7,8';

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT countryName 
FROM countries AS Country
INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n ON Country.id = n.country_id
WHERE n.network_id IN (".$networks.")";
```

However, if I want to select the network number 8, but NOT 6,7, how would I do that?

kind of a `IN('8') but NOT IN('6,7')`

The use of IN() is a not requirement.

I am after the countries that ONLY have a network of 8. The reason being is that I have 2 levels of cell-phone. Say, the 'scumbag-phone' that works in networks 6 & 7, and the 'Uber-phone' that works in networks 6,7 & 8.
I want to get the countries where it is essential that you have an Uber-phone (8 only). At the moment these queries will get 8, but not exclusively. They pay no heed to the fact that there may also be 6,7 in there, deeming the Uber-phone non-essential.

Comment: Please post complete structure of both tables and some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT countryName 
FROM countries AS Country
INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n ON Country.id = n.country_id
WHERE n.network_id in (8) AND not n.network_id  in (6, 7)
```

Comment: Hi Preet, see my above edits, I failed to clearly explain what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you do `IN('8')` then 6,7 will automatically not selected.

You're putting too much thought into this. But still if you want to write it, then do this:

```
n.network_id IN('8') AND n.network_id NOT IN(6,7)
```

Comment: yea, you're quite right, I am. Think I need a sit down in dark room. Thanks.

Comment: Actually thats what I'm doing already, but I want to select a countryName if there is ONLY a network id of 8, and nothing else, so if there is a 6,7 in the database, ignore that country completely. The above query does not consider that, it just ignores 6,7.

Answer (score 2):

You might not even need this answer anymore but I ran through some very similiar problem and I solved it by doing something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT countryName 
FROM countries AS Country
INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n ON Country.id = n.country_id
WHERE n.network_id IN ('8') and countryName not in (
    SELECT DISTINCT countryName 
    FROM countries AS Country
    INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n ON Country.id = n.country_id
    WHERE n.network_id IN ('6', '7')
);
```

With that you are exclusively selecting only the ones in which network_id is '8' and necessarily not '6' and '7'.

Answer (score 1):

There are no stupid questions, only stupid answers...

Here is my attempt:

'$query = "SELECT DISTINCT countryName 
FROM countries AS Country
INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n ON Country.id = n.country_id
WHERE n.network_id IN( "8")
AND n.network_id NOT IN( "6,7")
";`